# Who authored Vijnana Bhairav Tantra or what is it's Guru parampara?

Tags: yoga, tantra, shaivism, meditation, kashmiri-shaivism

Wikipedia says

> The Vijñāna-bhairava-tantra (VBT, sometimes spelled in a Hindicised
> way as Vigyan Bhairav Tantra) is a Shaiva Tantra, of the Kaula Trika
> tradition of Kashmir Shaivism, dated to ca. the 7th century CE. It is
> also called the Śiva-jñāna-upaniṣad by Abhinavagupta.

This only gives us info that the scripture was already there in 7CE and it belongs or highly in among Kashmiri Shavism.

But who authored it? When was it composed? What's the history of it?

The traditional opinion is that it doesn't have any human author instead it directly comes from Shiva. According to this traditional claim what is the Guru Paramapara through which the scripture has reached the public.

Either according to traditional account or according to modern research, what's tthe history of it?

Comment: Tantras don't have author. If they had we would be knowing them like Valmiki (for Ramayana) and Ved Vyasa (for Mahabharat) etc.

Comment: @Rickross Ok, but atleast do we have parampara trace?

Comment: That is a valid question to ask instead of asking  who the author is which is impossible to answer (as there is no such author). Usually the Tantras themselves contain the 3 paramparas through which that particular Tantra propagated among humans.